Automatically copy value from cell to another sheet in empty cell when box is checked and than uncheck the box
I have a sheet that tracks what products needs to be delivered to the factory during the week.
I want to have values of two columns (D & H) copied to column A (from sheet: WEEKPLANNING) in first empty cell on another sheet (DELIVERED) when the checkbox in column (G & K)
Now I managed to copy to values from sheet "WEEKPLANNING" column D & H to column A on the same sheet and then copy to column A in sheet "DELIVERED" with the function below.
My biggest issue is the values are not directly copied to the sheet "DELIVERED" and the sheet "WEEKPLANNING" only has 57 rows. So when the rows are filled it stops copying the values and when I delete the values from column A in "WEEKPLANNING", check a new box, it overwrites what's in column A in "DELIVERED"
function onEdit(e) {
    // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
    Object.prototype.get1stEmptyRowFromTop = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
      const range = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, 11&6);
      const values = range.getDisplayValues();
      if (values[0][0] && values[1][0]) {
        return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
      } else if (values[0][0] && !values[1][0]) {
        return offsetRow + 1;
      }
      return offsetRow;
    };

    var sheetName = "WEEKPLANNING";
    var { range } = e;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 11&6 || !range.isChecked()) return;
    range.offset(0, -3).copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(1), 1), { contentsOnly: true });
  
    const sourceAndDestinationSheet = ["WEEKPLANNING", "Blad4"]; // Please set the source sheet name and destination sheet name to the 1st and 2nd element.
  const dstHeader = ["LOSNR."]; // This is the header of the destination values.

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = sourceAndDestinationSheet.map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const [header, ...values] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Create an array of destination values.
  const colIndexes = dstHeader.map(h => header.indexOf(h));
  const dstValues = [dstHeader, ...values.map(r => colIndexes.map(i => r[i]))];

  // 3. Put the destination values to the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['G4:G55', 'K4:K55']).uncheck();

  }


Try something like this:
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const [d,,,g,h,,,k] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,11).getValues().flat(); //[d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
  if(sh.getName() == "WEEKPLANNING" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && (e.range.columnStart == 7 || e.range.columnStart == 11) && e.value == "TRUE" && g==true && k==true) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let osh = e.source.getSheetByName("DELIVERED");
    osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(`${d}\n${h}`)
  }
}


It doesn't work. When I check the box in column G he doesn't copy the corresponding value from column D or when I check the box in column K he also does not copy the value from column H to the sheet DELIVERED

I didn't set it up to work that way because you did not explain it well enough. I copy both when either column is checked and both are true.  If you wish a different operation then please update your question.  My code is working as it is written

I thought my explanation was not clear. I want to copy the corresponding values from  column D whenever the checkbox in column G is checked and copy the corresponding value from column H when the checkbox in column K is checked ("WEEKPLANNING") to the first empty cell in column A in "DELIVERED". After the value has been copied to "DELIVERED" uncheck the box.

Ok Please update the question
